# Formatting issues with links - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm experiencing problems with formatting links on HTML. I have a link, defined like so:

```
<a href="#a1" class="scroll type1">Some text</a>
```

As you can see, the link has two classes. The `scroll` class has no formatting whatsoever: it is just a marker for some lines of javascript code to scroll the page when the link is clicked. The `type1` class has css formatting. Here it is:

```
a.type1:link, a.type1:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.type1:hover {
    color: #4f8dd5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.type1:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So I expect the text of the link to be black, unless the user has the mouse over it, in which case it's blue.

However, that's not what happens. The hover is still correct, but this is what I see without the hover:

[image]

For some reason, the formatting in the css file is being ignored, and the default for links is being used.

Normal formatting only works if `a.type1:hover` is before everything else, but then that formatting isn't applied on hover.

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/gzdux/. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Works fine, something else is messing up your party!

Comment: Yes. Check for errors like a missing `}` above this chunk.

Comment: @Zenith Yes, it has to be! I couldn't figure out what was wrong with this, plus I have more `type_x` links which work perfectly. But I can't see any problem anywhere... I've tried on other html pages and the same happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry everyone... A stupid comment line was messing everything up. But like all good computers, I was ignoring that comment. Everything is perfect now. (Damn! I was around and around this for so much time just because of a comment on the css file...)